# Does greendao work in a multiprocess environment

Tags: android, greendao

**Is `greendao` intended to work in a multiprocess environment?**

Looking through the source, it does not appear to support multi process environment because of the way caching is handled and a few other things. I am looking for a confirmation or some more details from the developer.

With our current testing, we have it working great within 1 process with multiple threads. However, when we introduce a separate process accessing the same database we constantly get a `database is locked` exception.

---

Our test starts two different process' that both start two threads that are persisting randomly generated `daos` into the same database. And we have a third process that starts two threads that are constantly loading all the `daos` from the same database.

---

```
Failure 5 (database is locked) on 0x2d3050 when executing 'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;'

04-09 14:41:27.161: W/dalvikvm(20745): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
04-09 14:41:27.161: W/dalvikvm(20745): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
04-09 14:41:27.161: I/Process(20745): Sending signal. PID: 20745 SIG: 9
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1772)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:536)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:490)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.executeInsert(AbstractDao.java:344)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao.insert(AbstractDao.java:293)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at abc.def.ghi.MyDao.persist(MyDao.java:342)
04-09 14:41:27.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20745):    at abc.def.ghi.persistservice2.PersistThread.run(PersistThread.java:36)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supported by Android APIs for SQLite. Do you have any sources to verify that?

Comment: I do not believe it is supported natively by their sqlite wrapper. But their `ContentResolver` does support multiprocess access to the database. We actually had to go with a home grown solution with sqlite3. We put sqlite3 on the devices and wrote some code to allow our apps to use that. It is much faster than the `ContentResolver`. We are currently testing it for Concurrency issues and just normal bugs. Within a single app, `greendao` was faster than the `ContentResolver` by quite a bit, but we are working in a multiprocess environment. Thanks